# Converting Jackett api direct URL to magnet URL

Tags: perl, bittorrent

I'm working on a Perl program to download torrents using Jackett indexers and torznab APIs. For indexers that provide the magnet link directly in the XML this is super simple, but others provide a link (which appears to be an 'exact source' magnet link after some research)

**Goal: Convert this direct link to a 'magnet:?' URL or .torrent file for use with qbittorrent**

Here's what I have tried so far:

**WWW::Mechanize** (calling 'get' on the xs magnet URL)

```
Error GETing magnet:?<rest of magnet link>: Protocol scheme 'magnet' is not supported
```

**wget**

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: magnet:?<rest of magnet link>: Unsupported scheme ‘magnet’.
```

**curl** or **curl -o**

No value returned/blank file

I feel like there is a simple solution to this I just haven't had any success so far, sure I could filter the error message from mech or wget and pull the URL that way but that doesn't seem like the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
It appears this is a limitation of Jackett (or rather the indexers being accessed) in that a direct link cannot be provided through the api.

The solution to this is to take the redirect link from URL headers

```
curl '$URL' -si | grep -oP 'Location: \K.*'
```

Which in this case will return the magnet link

Answer (score 1):

That's not really how the protocol works. And, it's not simple.

The magnet scheme addresses content (so, that's the hashes you'll see) instead of a single location. You have to give that hash to something for it to return locations (multiple) where you can grab chunks of the content. Something like [Mojo::Transmission](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Transmission) might help. Searching MetaCPAN for BitTorrent has plenty of hits.

There are many [command line programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200544/12567) that might do what you want.

Comment: Thank you I'll look into Mojo::Transmission. I'm not sure I get where you are going with the command line link, I'm using qbittorrent-cli already but it isn't able to open the links provides by the indexers. (I wish I could post one of the URLs but it contains my API key along with possibly copyrighted content). Opening these links in a browser redirects to a magnet and opens qbittorrent, which is where I was going with curl and mech. Sorry about the wall of text, 'enter' on my phone apparently submits the comment instead of adding a line break

Comment: You can always expand your question to explain the problem and what you've already tried. I don't know what you're trying to do or why, so my answer is vague.

Comment: It appears this is a limitation of Jackett and there is no way to get the direct torrent link. Based on https://github.com/Jackett/Jackett/issues/5835